# Is Apache running?

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu-8.04

I've just taken over webmastery for my company's site, and I'm preparing a report for my partner about the LAMP stack. But I'm a new CS graduate, and the only thing I know really well is Java coding, so I need some help!

I'm trying to find out a) if Apache is installed and b) what version is running.

My Linux version is "Ubuntu 8.04.4 LTS \n \l", as reported by `/etc/issue`.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Is it running?

```
pgrep apache
```

Any output is good, nothing means it isn't running.

What version:

```
aptitude show apache2
```

Comment: `pgrep apache` produces 11 lines of output.

Comment: `aptitude show apache2` produces lots of output, including the line `Version: 2.2.8-1ubuntu0.15`.

Comment: `apache2 -version` in a shell would also work.

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried talking to it?

```
telnet localhost 80
HEAD / HTTP/1.0
<extra carriage return>
```

Comment: `telnet localhost 80` produces `-bash: telnet: command not found`

Comment: You should consider installing it or something with similar functionality such as ncat (part of nmap 5). Talking directly to your web (or SMTP or POP or IMAP or SIP or FTP or …) server can be indispensable for troubleshooting.

Answer (score 3):

**To check for Apache 1.X see below, for Apache 2.X see wzzrd's answer.**

The apache web server process is called httpd so a quick way to start with confirming apache is installed and running is:

**ps -A | grep 'httpd'**

ps -A lists all the running processes
grep 'httpd' filters only lines containing 'httpd'

If you don't get any results, apache is not running.

regarding version, try:

**apachectl status**

in the output there should be a line like:
 Apache/1.3.41 Server at www.xyz.com Port 80

If it cannot find apachectl, it may not be in your execution path, try:
**whereis apachectl**
to see where it is located

These are distribution agnostic ways so no matter how apache was installed on the system, you should find it with these.

Comment: "ps -A | grep 'httpd'" produces no output.

Comment: "apachectl status" produces "-bash: apachectl: command not found"

Comment: "whereis apachectl" produces "apachectl:"

Comment: However, `ps -A | grep apache2` produces ` 2691 ?        00:00:01 apache2` and 10 other `apache2` processes.

Comment: I appreciate the amount of effort you put into your answer, but I have to mark you down because these are not "distribution agnostic" ways  to determinte how apache was installed. Apparently on Ubuntu the process is called `apache2`. See wzzrd's answer: http://serverfault.com/questions/177915/is-apache-running/177930#177930

Comment: @isme, actually, that isn't a distribution issue but an apache major version issue. I was referencing a box with apache 1.x on it. The instructions would have worked on Ubuntu with apache 1.x and the other answer would have not produced a result.

Answer (score 0):

```
/sbin/service httpd status
```

Will say that you don't have it | it's OK | it's OFF

Comment: `/sbin/service httpd status` produces `-bash: /sbin/service: No such file or directory`

Answer (score 0):

Click here: http://localhost If you don't get an error 404, it's running.

Comment: My server instance is a VPS, so I can't just click a link on my local machine to check whether it's running.

Comment: You could run some ncurses web browser like links or lynx directly on the server.

Comment: There are many reasons why http://localhost might not give a 404 error . For example, another server may be running. Also, it's possible for Apache to return a 404 error when it is running.

Answer (score 0):

For Apache/2.2.22 you can also try. It will show you a few processes.

```
ps -A | grep 'apache'
```

Answer (score 0):

Newer Ubuntu versions use systemd, which means you can use the command `systemctl` for this purpose:

```
$ systemctl is-active apache2
active
```

If you don't need the output, but want to use the status in an if statement in a shell script, you can use the `--quiet` option, like this:

```
if systemctl is-active --quiet apache2 ; then
   echo "apache2 is running"
else
   echo "apache2 is not running"
fi
```

#### Reference:

- [Unix&Linux question: The "proper" way to test if a service is running in a script](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/396630/9041)