# One app, several virtual host and multiple apache instances

Tags: apache-2.4, load-balancing, ubuntu-14.04, mpm-prefork, multiple-instances

We are having a problem in witch from time to time our apache2 server stops working. When I try to restart it I need to first kill several existing running instances of apache.

Like this:

```
sudo service apache2 restart
pidof apache2
sudo kill -9 <pid>
sudo service apache2 start
```

When I run pidof command I can get up to 12 ids. I understand that this is [perfectly normal](https://serverfault.com/questions/177981/is-this-many-apache-instances-normal). However there might be a better solution for what we are trying to accomplish.

We are an commerce platform for the Peruvian market. Think of it as a small version of Shopify. We have over 200 stores running the same application. Each store runs under its own domain and SSL certificate, so we have created several virtual host. Although all of them points to the same directory.

Most of this sites have very little traffic and our application runs smoothly most of the time. However if a store have a peek of traffic, CPU usage grows up to 100% and the server crashes. See the [attached image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CNJSi.png).

How could I prevent the server from crashing?
Do you think using a  load balancer might help?
Is there a better solution than running several virtual host?
What is your recommended setup for [Multi-Processing Module](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/prefork.html)?

Thanks

Comment: New server in your pools ?

Comment: This should work as described. I think you need to see what's happening when the box hits 100%  - is your DB on the same box and maybe they are conflicting when under load?

Comment: Database is on separate droplet on the same region. The connection to the database uses a private local IP